# How can I save the textbox content to the application itself?

Tags: vb.net

Simply put, for example, I want to save content of a textbox to the application itself.

I tried "My.Settings" but type of settings must be "user-scoped" & settings(string content of textbox) extracting to %appdata% folder(user.config).

**I want store the data(confidential text) on the application without extracting it to anywhere.**

On the other hand "application-scoped" settings are "Read-Only" and values of settings can not be change while type of settings "application-scoped". I want settings(string content of textbox) always changeable by the user of app.

TextFile in Resources is also read-only...I have to extract TextFile for changing the content of TextFile.

How can i do that?

Comment: When you say "on the application" do you mean part of the .exe?

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with using user scoped settings?  Sounds like exactly what you wanting to do isn’t?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `My.Computer.Filesystem.WriteAllText()` & `My.Computer.Filesystem.ReadAllText()` to write/read files. And there's no better way.

But yeah, you can achieve your requirement by saving the data into Registry, i.e. if you want to save your any text data which is accessible anywhere from the device, it could really be helpful.

Note that your application will require to be ran as administrator for saving/reading registry values.

To save registry value:

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\something", "ValueName", "Value")
```

To access it:

```
My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("Same Location", "Same ValueName", Nothing) ' Note that "Nothing" is returned when value doesn't exists.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for replying. Instead of saving the data to somewhere and calling it from there, I wanted to store it in the application itself. In that case app-based data storing impossible. I think it makes more sense to store confidential text content on a private server and calling it from there.

Comment: Nope mate. That's why My.Settings feature is developed for a .NET application. If you internally wants to save data, you can use it. Otherwise, you must need to use something external thing. That's it.